# phpmyadmin disable notification

Tags: phpmyadmin, notifications, popup

phpmyadmin 3.5.8.1

Whenever I change something in a table there is a very redundant notification telling me I just changed something. Sometimes it's even blocking the next thing I want to adjust and regardless I have the urge to click the notification to make it leave. Is there a way to disable this kind of notifications ? I tried looking in the documentation, but it doesn't help that I don't know the official name of this kind of thing .. warnings, popups, messages, notifications ?

(I have a screenshot of it, but it seems I need 10 reputation first to post images, so I hope my description is good enough)

Comment: Yes! I am starting feel a need to delete phpMyAdmin. These notifications are just annoying.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to update many next to next content

first of all edit any content then use ctrl+shift+navigation[**<**,**>**,**^**,**v**] to switch to next field and update without notificaton